# Create tidy multiple reduce function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

I would like to replace this (`want`) with a function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)
create_a <- function() {
      list(x = 1:10, y = data.frame(aa = round(rnorm(10, 2000, 10), 0),
                                bb = sample(letters[3:8], 10, replace = T),
                                stringsAsFactors = F))
}

create_b <- function() {
  list(x = 1:10, y = data.frame(aa = round(rnorm(10, 10, 1), 0),
                                bb = sample(letters[3:8], 10, replace = T),
                                stringsAsFactors = F))
}  

want <- list(x = reduce(map(list(create_a(), create_b()), 1), c),
             y = reduce(map(list(create_a(), create_b()), 2), rbind)) # or bind_rows
```

There are multiple functions (`create_a` and `create_b`) which create output-lists with elements that have the same names. In contrast to the examples above, the calculations in the actual functions are quite different. 
The function should look like this:

```
multiple_reduce <- function(...) {
  # ????
}
want <- multiple_reduce(create_a(), 
                        create_b())
```

How do you do that using a tidy approach?

`want` should look like this in both cases:

```
$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$y
     aa bb
1  2014  e
2  1999  g
3  2004  e
4  1999  d
5  1986  g
6  1996  d
7  1996  g
8  1999  c
9  2011  d
10 2008  c
11    9  h
12   10  g
13   11  e
14   10  e
15   11  c
16   10  c
17    9  g
18   10  c
19    9  e
20   11  f
```

Comment: Could you provide current and expected output? It's currently an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Do you want to combine them based on same name? Or based on same type?

Comment: I would like to combine the `x`'s (or positions 1 in the different lists) to a single, aggregated `x`, and the `y` 's to a `y`. The order and the names of the result lists of the functions I want to aggregate are the same.

Comment: Is this close: `map2(create_a(),create_b(),function(x,y) rbind(x,y))`?

Comment: Yes, except that the vectors should be concatenated (`c`). `pmap(create_a(),create_b(), create_b(),function(...) rbind(...))` on the other hand seems not to work.

Comment: You mean the first ouptut(the x, right?)

Comment: Yes, the aggregation function should be `c` for variable `x` and `bind_rows` or `rbind` for the `y` data frames.

Comment: Had issues with `seed`, so maybe you could also try: `map2(create_a(),create_b(),function(x,y) rbind(x,y)) %>% 
  modify_at("x",function(x) x[!duplicated(x)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe one way would be to combine all the inputs together and split them based on their name so that we have list with similar names together. We can then check if the lists are of atomic type and combine them as one vector or dataframe accordingly.

```
library(tidyverse)

multiple_reduce <- function(a, b, ...) {
   combine_list <- c(a, b, ...)
   new_list <- split(combine_list, names(combine_list))
   list(x = map(new_list, ~keep(., is.atomic)) %>% flatten %>% reduce(c),
        y = map(new_list, ~discard(., is.atomic)) %>% flatten %>% bind_rows)
}

multiple_reduce(create_a(), create_b())

#$x
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$y
#     aa bb
#1  2001  g
#2  1998  h
#3  2003  g
#4  1971  h
#5  1998  h
#6  2001  f
#7  1993  d
#8  1990  c
#9  2009  d
#10 2019  d
#11   10  h
#12    9  d
#13   10  g
#14    8  f
#15   11  e
#16    9  c
#17   12  c
#18   10  f
#19   10  c
#20    8  h
```

This will also work with multiple such lists

```
multiple_reduce(create_a(), create_b(), create_a(), create_b())
```